# Read data from server using IP address and Store in Text file in C#

Tags: c#

I'm able to read data from the Server (IP Camera) continuously, which sends the data after every 200 ms. I'm storing the incoming data in a List and later when  I disconnect the Server, all the data from List should get printed to Text file. But the entire program is getting stuck when I read data continuously using while(true) loop, due to which I'm unable to click on Disconnect Button. Also, the same data is not getting stored into the Text file. Kindly, help me out at the earliest.

Thank you.

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: You should use another `thread` to read the data, so it will not block the _main thread_. You may do your homework on how to do that, and then post your code if you have other problem

Comment: It seems to me that you're blocking the ui thread, entering a deadlock or something..

Answer (score 2):

Seems that your poblem is related to the fact that you are using a loop cycle inside the `UI Thread` and for this reason you can not click on any other `UI element` in the form because the UI thread is locked by `while(true)`.
The easiest solution to your problem is running your loop cycle inside a separate `Thread`.

Answer (score 0):

Your While loop is running on UI Thread, so you should run this loop in background thread. you can use [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Background](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground(v=vs.110).aspx) [Thread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread(v=vs.110).aspx).